# After pseudo is not symmetrically positioned horizontally and vertically, despite having same style

Tags: html, css, frontend

I have a button and an `::after` pseudo which sits behind it, to give the impression of having a border beneath it. It's placed `3px` "away" from the button, but for some reason, the right side placement doesn't look the same as the bottom.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCDwU.png

The button is:
`<button class="btn btn-action">agreed</button>`.

Some of the styles applied to the button.

```
.btn {
position: relative;
font-weight: 700;
letter-spacing: 0.125rem;
border-width: 0;
white-space: nowrap;
text-align: center;
text-transform: uppercase;
font-style: normal;
font-family: 'custom_font';
display: inline-flex;
align-items: center;
}

.btn::after {
content: '';
position: absolute;
border: 0.125rem solid #000;
z-index: -1;
height: auto;
left: 0.25rem;
right: -0.25rem;
top: 0.25rem;
bottom: -0.25rem;
}

.btn-action {
font-size: 0.875rem;
padding: 0.8125rem 1.25rem;
height: 3.125rem;
background-color: #000;
border-color: #000;
line-height: 1;
z-index: 1;
}

.btn-action::after {
border-width: 1px;
top: 0.1875rem;
bottom: -0.1875rem;
left: 0.1875rem;
right: -0.1875rem;
}
```

The button also comes with a `font-weight: 700` and for some reason, when disabling that style, it works perfectly, but I do need the font weight there. :(

Any idea what could cause this?

Sandbox
https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-khayyam-4wglo9

Comment: add you html code as well

Comment: @TheDuo I have.

Comment: Running your sandbox code does not reproduce the problem for me - the distances are the same. I am on Edge/Windows10. What browser/OS are you using?

Comment: @AHaworth Chrome/Windows 10.

Comment: there was no problem for me either in codesandbox

Answer (score 0):

your problem it's not font-weight, in css we have one `::before` and one `::after` for an element, so here your `.btn` and `.btn-action` are same using one after for two different purpose make overriding styles and problems and this snippet may help you I delete some of the unused styles here:

```css
.btn {
  position: relative;
  font-weight: 700;
  letter-spacing: 0.125rem;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  border: none;
  font-style: normal;
  font-family: 'custom_font';
  color: #fff;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn::before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  border: 0.125rem solid #000;
  z-index: -1;
  height: auto;
  left: 0.25rem;
  right: -0.25rem;
  top: 0.25rem;
  bottom: -0.25rem;
}

.btn-action {
  font-size: 0.875rem;
  padding: 0.8125rem 1.25rem;
  height: 3.125rem;
  background-color: #000;
  line-height: 1;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-action">agreed</button>
```

Comment: I'm using `.btn-action::after` because there's another button styled with the pseudo having that border (`btn::after`), but as you can see, it's got slightly more distance. So for `btn-action`, I simply reused that `btn::after` and applied less distance. So I am not sure why you'd use `::before`?